# Error Running Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Am new to spring boot.Any time I run my spring boot app, i get error.
Need help in running my spring boot application.

error message:
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Oct 10 10:39:54 WAT 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

code:

```
    package hello;

    import org.springframework.ui.Model;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

    @RestController
    public class GreetingController {

        @RequestMapping("/greeting")
        public String greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name, Model model) {
            model.addAttribute("name", name);
            return "greeting";
        }

    }


package com.HelloWorld;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class HelloWorldApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HelloWorldApplication.class, args);
    }
}

 - greeting.html

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <p th:text="'Hello, ' + ${name} + '!'" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which URL are you trying to access?

Answer (score 2):

Issue is because your controller is in a different package structure than your spring boot application class, in such  case @ComponentScan needs to be added to the Spring Boot application class.

Try this :

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"hello"})
```

Comment: The SpringBootApplication annotation is equivalent to using Configuration, EnableAutoConfiguration and ComponentScan with their default attributes, it by default scans for all beans with the Component annotation (or "sub"annotations like Controller, Service etc.).

Comment: But it always looks for all beans under its package scan and will not able to scan controllers in different package

Comment: it is able, you can try